# Grails many to many passing multiple values from gsp to controller to save

Tags: list, grails, save, gsp

I have a many to many relationship between forms and events, in a list using a join table and when I display the data in edit mode I show each item in its own dropdown in a table as opposed to one multi select dropdown list.  I also have a little jQuery in there to add extra dropdowns in if I want to add more items, My question is, how do I then save back this set of "events", in order?  Code is as follows: -

Initial _form.gsp to load all linked events for the form: -

```
   <table id="eventList">
        <g:each in="${formInstance?.events}" status = "i" var="item">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <td>
                    <label></label>
                    <g:select name="event_${i}" from="${framework.Event.list()}" required="required" optionKey="id" value="${item.id}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </table>
```

Additional objects are added with this gsp

```
<tr class="${((newRow+1) % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
    <td>
        <label></label>
            <g:select name="event_${newRow-1}" from="${framework.Event.list()}" required="required" optionKey="id" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

The save button currently is as such: -

```
<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
```

And the Update action is unchanged from the one generated automatically from the domain setup.  How do I get the save to recognise the new fields added?  Currently hitting save does to the "events", even if I change the order...

Domain Classes are as such

```
import java.util.List;

class Form {
    static constraints = {
        formDesc(blank:false,maxSize:100,unique: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "form"
        version false
        columns{
            id column:"form_id"
            formDesc column:"description"
            testscenarios joinTable:[name:"lnk_scenario_form",key:'form_id']
            events joinTable:[name:"lnk_form_event",key:'form_id']
        }
    }

    String formDesc
    List events

    static hasMany = [testscenarios:TestScenario, events:Event]
    static belongsTo = fartframework.TestScenario

    String toString (){
        "${formDesc}"
    }
}
```

And

```
class Event {
       static constraints = {
           eventTypeID()
           eventOrder()
           objectID()
           testDataID()
        }

    static mapping = {
        table "event_form"
        version false
        columns{
            id column:"event_form_id"
            eventTypeID column:"event_id"
            eventOrder column:"event_order"
            testDataID column:"test_data_id"
            objectID column:"object_id"

            forms joinTable:[name:"lnk_form_event", key:'event_id']
        }
    }

    EventType eventTypeID
    Integer eventOrder
    TestData testDataID
    Object objectID

    static hasMany = [forms:Form]
    static belongsTo = fartframework.Form

    String toString (){
        "${eventTypeID}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that your hasMany is named "events", try `name="events[$i].id"`.

Comment: When I change it to this and then attempt to just change the order of things that are already there I get the following error `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__lnk_form__7B3919BB0AD2A005'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.lnk_form_event'.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__lnk_form__7B3919BB0AD2A005'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.lnk_form_event'.` Any ideas?  Its certainly further on from where I was as before nothing at all happened! :)

Comment: I also get this error if I add a new dropdown and then attempt to save on that, without changing the previous fields... Works fine if I start from scratch though with a form with no events, but once its been saved I cannot updated or alter it :S  I'm using SQL server if that's of any use...?

Comment: Can you post your domain classes?

Comment: Have added as requested :)

Comment: I was incorrect in my previous comment that I can't add new fields, I can add new ones to my hearts content, but the minute I attempt to change an existing one, OR add in a duplicate I get the bang.  I'm guessing its to do with grails not understanding that the values have changed and its trying to do an insert without clearing out existing values first, has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was because my link table had a primary key set on both the form_id AND event_id combination columns, which I don't care about as I WANT to be able to have duplicates in there (as its the order that's more important), removing these primary key values on the table solved the problem!

I do still have the issue that if I now add/remove a bunch of times I get problems with identical names and the issues that represents, but I can work round that one with some jquery hacking (I hope)...